# Entropy Calculation as a Linguist Feature

Tags: python, nlp, lstm, entropy, linguistics

I was going through a paper on Sarcasm Detection which proposed a Hybrid Attention Based LSTM. The Model included some linguistic features to be extracted first, which included Entropy of a word in a sentence. Unfortunately, the paper does not explain it very well. The explanation given is:

> The entropy of a word is defined as the degree of randomness of a word
> concerning the sentence. It is calculated using the following
> equation:
> S(A/B) = (p(ai / bj) ∗ log(p(ai))) / p(bj)
>  where
> S(A/B) represents the probability of the word ‘A’ with respect to the
> sentence ‘B’, and p(ai / bj) means the probability of ai given bi.

If someone understands the terms, kindly explain these.

Title of Paper: **Hybrid attention-based Long Short-Term Memory network for
sarcasm identification**
[Link to Paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1568494621002714#b41)